# EF 6 and Web Api. How return custom data on GET?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I need to return from Web Api controller some specific data that not exist in standard GET action. Let's say standard controller action is:

```
// GET api/xTourist/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(xTourist))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetxTourist(int id)
        {
            xTourist xtourist = db.xTourist.Find(id);
            if (xtourist == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(xtourist);
```

But I need to return some more data, let's say hotel name. Hotel name I got by using function:

```
public string FindHotelName (int id)
        {
            int? hotelid = db.xTourist.Find(id).КодИ;
            string hotelname = db.xAdres.Find(hotelid).NameC;
            return hotelname;
        }
```

But how should I joind these data and return it all together in controller answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want the 2 results returned?  Why not just create a new object which holds both the values you need?

```
public class TouristReturnDTO
{
    public xTourist Tourist { get; set; }
    public string HotelName { get; set; }
}

public IHttpActionResult GetxTourist(int id)
{
    xTourist xtourist = db.xTourist.Find(id);
    if (xtourist == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    string hotelName = FindHotelName(id)
    return Ok(new TouristReturnDto
        {
            Tourist = xtourist,
            HotelName = hotelName
        }
    );
}
```

Don't even need to create the TouristReturnDTO, could just use an anonymous type if you want:

```
return Ok(new 
        {
            Tourist = xtourist,
            HotelName = hotelName
        }
    );
```

Comment: Look like it's what I need. Thanks a lot!